# Can't pull proper information with Azure python SDK or update storage account

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I am trying to update Azure storage accounts through the Azure python SDK. I follow the documentation and can authenticate against Azure just fine.

However when I run code to update the parameters of the storage account I get the following error:
'minimum_tls_version is not a known attribute of class <class 'azure.mgmt.storage.v2019_06_01.models._models_py3.StorageAccountUpdateParameters'> and will be ignored'

reference from microsoft saying it should exist: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-storage/azure.mgmt.storage.v2019_06_01.models.storageaccountupdateparameters?view=azure-python

Code in question: storage_account = self.storage.storage_accounts.update(resource_group, storage_account_name, StorageAccountUpdateParameters(enable_https_traffic_only=True, minimum_tls_version='TLS1_1' ))

Any help or direction is appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

This parameter is a new parameter released in version 11.1.0 release on 2020-6-22. Any chance you are using an old package? The doc would show the latest one only.

ChangeLog is available on PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-storage/

(I work at MS in the SDK team)

Comment: Yes I just doubled checked that it was updated properly. Maybe I am putting this in wrong:
self.storage = StorageManagementClient(credentials, SUBSCRIPTION)
        self.client.providers.register('Microsoft.Storage')

        
        storage_account = self.storage.storage_accounts.update(resource_group, storage_account_name, StorageAccountUpdateParameters(enable_https_traffic_only=True,allow_blob_public_access=False))

Comment: Figured it out: I had downloaded the most 'update to date' Azure storage SDK but it didn't. I went and downloaded the most recent version, specifically 11.1.0

Thanks for the insight! Solid work on the SDK

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad it's working now :). On top of the Stackoverflow, if you have any questions you can always ask a question on Github too https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues. Have a great rest of your day :)